# How to write this query in yii?

Tags: php, sql, database, yii

```
 SELECT business.id,business.business_name,address.city FROM business INNER JOIN address ON business.id=address.business_id WHERE business.business_name like '%monal%' and address.city='islamabad'
```

Where monal and islamabad would be a value coming from a form.
when i replace islamabad with a variable it gives me error.
My query in yii.

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('business.id,business_name,business.image,business.business_description,address.city')
    ->from('business')
    ->join('address', 'business.id=address.business_id')
    //->where(array('like', 'business.business_name', '%'.$name.'%'))   
    ->where(array('and', 'address.city=$city', array('like', 'business.business_name', '%'.$name.'%')))
    ->queryALL();



 CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Islamabad' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `business`.`id`, `business_name`, `business`.`image`, `business`.`business_description`, `address`.`city`
FROM `business`
JOIN `address` ON business.id=address.business_id
WHERE (address.city=Islamabad) AND (`business`.`business_name` LIKE '%nan%')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as your query instead

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('b.id, b.business_name, a.city')
    ->from('business b')
    ->join('address a', 'b.id = a.business_id')
    ->where('b.business_name LIKE :businessName AND a.city = :city', array(
        ':businessName' => '%' . $businessNameVariable . '%',
        ':city' => $cityVariable,
    ))
    ->queryAll();
```

Comment: i am trying to understand, but my knowledge is very limited, now how can i use foreach loop to print the values? i am trying this but error is coming foreach($results as $item){
    //process each item here
    $name[]=$item['b.business_name'];
 echo $name[$i];
 echo " ";$i++;}

Comment: Undefined index: b.business_name

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeah :D

Comment: i changed $name[]=$item['b.business_name']; with $name[]=$item['business_name']; it is working thanks so much sir :)

Comment: if you have five more minutes then please explain your code, its my final year project so i have to know each and everything